# Convert datatype using parameter - ChangeType() scope issue

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I want to convert a var based on the Type of another variable.

The reason for this is that I have an extension method that will apply a calculation on T providing T is a double, float or decimal (I test for the correct Type at the beginning of the method).

So anyway, testing the conversion with the following code snippet throws an error:

```
      List<double> source = new List<double>();
      source.Add(1);
      Type typ = source.First().GetType();
      var newVal = Convert.ChangeType(source.First(), typeof(typ));  //error: typ not found
```

> The type or namespace name 'typ' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

However, this works fine:

```
      List<double> source = new List<double>();
      source.Add(1);
      Type typ = source.First().GetType();
      var newVal = Convert.ChangeType(source.First(), typeof(double));
```

Comment: `typeof` does not accept a variable as a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

note that a `Type` object and a reference to a type are *not* the same thing.

While `Type typ` creates an *object* of type `Type`, `typeof(T)` returns a `Type` object based on the `T`, which is known at compile time (for generics, this is JIT-compile time, but it works the same).

Thus, you cannot use a `Type` object for a generic parameter directly, because it's an object, not a type reference.

Note, however, that since `typeof` returns a `Type` object, this case can be solved by using `typ` directly.

```
  List<double> source = new List<double>();
  source.Add(1);
  Type typ = source.First().GetType();
  var newVal = Convert.ChangeType(source.First(), typ);
```